# Loading ggplot2 package, missing 'munsell' package

Tags: r

I am trying to load ggplot2.  I am using Windows 7.  R tells me that ggplot2 has loaded successfully but when I try to use the `library` function it says it cannot find ggplot2.  Here is what it says.

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/ggplot2_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2675581 bytes (2.6 Mb)
opened URL
downloaded 2.6 Mb

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyesS1j\downloaded_packages
```

I then tried to use the `library` function and got this message:

```
library("ggplot2")
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘munsell’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
> head(diamonds)
Error in head(diamonds) : object 'diamonds' not found
```

I hope someone has an idea about what I have done wrong.

Comment: `install.packages("munsell")`?

Comment: In your error message, you have `there is no package called ‘munsell’`. Have you tried `install.packages("munsell")`, then trying again?

Comment: Just to clarify, RStudio is an IDE, and embeds R 'seamlessly'. Most of the time it has nothing to do with issues produced within R.

Answer (score 4):

You *should*  have executed this:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I did what you suggested as well as what some others suggested which is to install munsell and everything worked .  Again, Thank you for the timely advice.