# R install package caret

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-caret

I am trying to install the `caret` package. It is successfully installed but when I try to load the `library(caret)` I get the following error.

```
library(caret)
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘munsell’
Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded
```

I tried several suggestions but always get the same error.

Comment: It looks like you don't have the required package `munsell` installed. Just install it like you did install `caret` and `ggplot2`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569716/loading-ggplot2-package-missing-munsell-package